# Permutation with Spaces

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am solving the Permutation with Spaces problem. I was able to solve it but there are few doubts i have which i got by solving the question related to python recursion

```
class Solution:
   def solve(self, inp, output, index, ans):
       if index == len(inp):
           ans.add(output)
           return

       char = inp[index]

       self.solve(inp, output + char, index + 1, ans)
       if index > 0:
           self.solve(inp, output + " " + char, index + 1, ans)
       else:
           self.solve(inp, output + char, index + 1, ans)

   def permutation(self, S):
       ans = set()
       index = 0
       output = ""
       self.solve(S, output, index, ans)
       a = list(ans)
       a.sort()
       return a

obj = Solution()
S = "ABC"
print(obj.permutation(S))
```

The above is my working code

```
class Solution:
   def solve(self, inp, output, index, ans):
       if index == len(inp):
           ans.append(output)
           return

       char = inp[index]

       self.solve(inp, output + char, index + 1, ans)
       if index > 0:
           self.solve(inp, output + " " + char, index + 1, ans)
       else:
           self.solve(inp, output + char, index + 1, ans)

   def permutation(self, S):
       ans = []
       index = 0
       output = ""
       self.solve(S, output, index, ans)
       a = list(ans)
       a.sort()
       return a

obj = Solution()
S = "ABC"
print(obj.permutation(S))
```

This code gives answers with duplicates

Like this

['A B C', 'A B C', 'A BC', 'A BC', 'AB C', 'AB C', 'ABC', 'ABC']

```
class Solution:
   def solve(self, inp, output, index, ans):
       if index == len(inp):
           ans.append(output)
           return

       char = inp[index]

       output += char
       self.solve(inp, output, index + 1, ans)

       output += " " + char
       self.solve(inp, output, index + 1, ans)

   def permutation(self, S):
       ans = []
       index = 0
       output = ""
       self.solve(S, output, index, ans)
       a = list(ans)
       a.sort()
       return a


obj = Solution()
S = "ABC"
print(obj.permutation(S))
```

if i run this code
This code is giving duplicates like this

['A AB BC', 'A AB BC C', 'A ABC', 'A ABC C', 'AB BC', 'AB BC C', 'ABC', 'ABC C']

I want to know why my solve recursion function was returning duplicates

Comment: You used a `set`, which dedupes, in the first case. You used a `list`, which does not, in the second case. What more are you looking for?